# Show that the rings $R_1=F_5[x]/(x^2)$ and $R_2=F_5\times F_5$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Show that the rings $R_1=F_5[x]/(x^2)$ and $R_2=F_5\times F_5$ are not isomorphic.($F_5$ is the field with $5$ elements.)

My Work:

Since $(0,1)$ does not have an inverse, $F_5\times F_5$ is not a field. Since $x^2$ is reducible in $F_5[x]$, $F_5[x]/(x^2)$ is not a field. Also both $R_1,R_2$ have same number of elements. So, I was fail to prove that they are not isomorphic. Is there any property that do not satisfied by them together?

Comment: Just count the number of zero divisors.

Comment: Do you mean zero divisors?

Comment: Even though it may seem obvious from context, can you edit your post to include your working definition of $F_5$?

Comment: @idm Can you please explain why it is irreducible?

Comment: @Mathi: sorry, it's reducible (my english is not very, I often do confusion). Forget my previous message :-)

Comment: one has nilpotents, the other doesn't

Comment: @yoyo, that is precisely the content of egreg's answer...

Comment: $x^2$ is not reducible in any sense in $F_5[x]/(x^2)$, as it is equal to zero there...

Comment: @  Mariano Suárez-Alvarez♦: $x^2$ is reducible in $F_5[x]$, not in $F_5[x]/(x^2)$. I did not say that it is reducible in $F_5[x]/(x^2)$!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: one ring has non-zero nilpotent elements, the other one hasn't.

Answer (score 2):

(1). Let $A$ and $B$ be two rings (commutative with $1$) and let $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism. If $\phi$ is an isomorphism then every non-zero nilpotent element of $A$ will map to a non-zero nilpotent element of $B.$

In this case, $A:= R_1$ contains a non-zero nilpotent element, $x + (x^2),$ but $B:= R_2$ has no non-zero nilpotent element.

(2). $R_1$ has only one prime ideal, the ideal generated by $x + (x^2)$ where as $R_2$ has two prime ideals, $ 0 \times F_5$ and $F_5 \times 0.$

Comment: How do you say that $(x)$ is an element of $R_1$?

Comment: @Mathi: it was a typo. I mean $\overline{x}$ or $x + (x^2).$

Comment: So how did you show that it is nilpotent? Which power $m$ gives $(x+(x^2))^m=(x^2)$?

Comment: take $m = 2.$ it is the smallest integer with this property.